# Divison of Fractions

Tags: fractions

Intuitively answer of $(1/1)/(1/(5^{-2}))=25$ But assuming this mathematical logic of evaluating $(a/b) /(c/d) = (a*d) / (b*c)$  equation evaluates to $1/25$.

Is there any specified rule to put parenthesis ..

What i have studied in operator associativity is / is having left to right associativity which evaluates the above to 25 .

[Google Result of 1/1/1/5^-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5VQH.png)

Comment: Why do you say intuitively the answer is $25$?

Comment: replace $5^{-2}$ by $(5^2)^{-1}$

Comment: @littleO i have written it as 1/1/1/5^-2

Comment: Request to person who edited question please make it as 1/1/1/5^-2

Comment: The parentheses are important.  $(12/6)/2 \neq 12/(6/2)$.

Comment: @littleO i know it but if they are not given how parenthesis will be applied on it

Comment: If parentheses aren't given, and you just have an expression like $1/1/1/5^{-2}$, then I think the convention is to perform the divisions from left to right.  When you originally asked this question, I think you gave the expression $(1/1)/(1/5^{-2})$.  We can't just throw away those parentheses and expect to get the same answer.

Comment: @littleO: "the convention is to perform the divisions from left to right": I agree. That's certainly how a compiler would do it. Any other convention would be insane, so the question is, do we just go ahead and evaluate it as $((1/1)/1)/5^{-2}$, or do we refuse to evaluate it, insisting on disambiguating parentheses?

Comment: @TonyK: ... Any convention would be alright. Even if I evaluate an equivalent statement as $a/(b/(c/d))$ , it's not actually wrong because I wasn't given any brackets and I'm like blind and sitting in a dark room, the only way I can move on is by just guessing where things are. I can either guess with my walking stick (like a compiler evaluating pairs) or I could tap into my inner primate and ask the spirits of my ancestors what my surroundings look like (like a hippy math dude that's high on symmetry)

Comment: @Nick: In view of your comment, I retract my 'insane' judgment. I am prepared to weaken it to 'disturbed'.

Comment: @TonyK: I'm sorry if poetic thought sounds abnormal to your logical instruments. What I meant to say was that although $((a/b)/c)/d$ is how computers do it, the human convention is $(a/b)/(c/d)$ due to our centered mindset.

Answer (score 2):

This is where you're wrong:

$\dfrac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{1}}{5^2} = \frac{1}{25} \neq 25$

Most likely, because you've forgotten that $5^{-2} = \frac{1}{5^2}$

Comment: 1/1/1/5-2  = 1/1/25 = 25  , whats wrong in it if brackets are not given ..

Answer (score 2):

The traditional method may seem strange:
$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{ad}{bc} $$

This isn't any magic trick. It's just that we are assuming that $\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{(\frac{a}{b})}{(\frac{c}{d})}$

$$\large
 \frac
    { \frac
         { \color{red}{a} }
         { \color{blue}{b} }
    }
    { \frac
           { \color{green}{c} }
           { \color{orange}{d} }
    } 
= \frac
    { \color{red}{a} }
    { \color{blue}{b} } 
       \div 
  \frac
 { \color{green}{c} }{ \color{orange}{d} } 
= \frac{\color{red}a}{\color{blue}b} \times \frac{\color{orange}d}{\color{green}c} 
= \frac{\color{red}{a}\color{orange}{d}}{\color{blue}{b}\color{green}{c}}$$

So naturally,
$$\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}} = \frac{1}{1} \cdot \frac{5^{-2}}{1} = 5^{-2} = \frac{1}{25}$$

Again, please do bear in mind that 
$$x^{-n} = (x^n)^{-1} = \frac1{x^n} \implies 5^{-2} = \frac{1}{5^2} = \frac{1}{5\times 5} = \frac1{25}$$

---

But there *is* a problem when a non-human does it:

If you enter $1\div 1\div 1 \div 5^{-2}$ into some old calculator, it could give you the wrong answer because of the way it prefers to evaluate the statement. So it'll end up:
$$ (((1\div 1)\div 1) \div 5^{-2}) = \frac{(\frac{(1/1)}{1})}{5^{-2}} = 5^2 = 25$$

**Why? ::** When you have $a\star b\star c \star d$ where $\star$ is some binary operation, one can only guess how  the order of operation is going to be. A binary operation is made to only take in 2 guys and spit out 1 guy. 
If brackets are not provided to indicate how to evaluate it, we would simply choose the easiest way for us to evaluate.

We, as human beings, like symmetry and order so we naturally pair it as:
$$(a\star b)\star (c \star d) $$

But a computer is impatient to look at the whole thing would evaluate the statement as it is read from left to right:
$$((a\star b)\star c) \star d$$

Actually, the convenient way of thinking about it is that the computer is giving more priority to the binary-ness of the operation by focusing on creating pairs (of $x\star y$) first. So after it evaluates $a\star b$ and in memory turns it into a single entity, it then evaluates $(a\star b)\star c$ which is again stored as a single entity and finally outputes the result of $((a\star b)\star c)\star d$

---

There are scientific calculator with natural displays that allow you to enter such fractions in the same way we write them on paper (in $\frac{x}{y}$ form) so that confusions like yours do not arise.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Intuitively-answer-of-1-1-1-5-2-25-But-going-to-traditional-mathematical-logic-of-evaluating-a-b-c-d-a*d-b*c-By-this-above-equation-evaluates-to-1-25-Where-I-am-wrong/answer/Obaidur-Rahman-4/comment/5964030?__snids__=614737333&__nsrc__=2&__filter__=priority#comment5964093

Comment: I also get that calculator can give wrong results  but it would be your great help if you can provide some reference where its told that parenthesis are to put in some spefied fashion

Comment: @ATulSingh: How the parenthesis is put depends on the calculator, whether it be human or machine. I've added an explanation in my answer.

Comment: Left to right associativity is followed here from that we will get 25

Comment: @ATulSingh: Yes, exactly. But I screwed up in the explanation of that earlier. Now, I've corrected it and expanded on it. Please do read it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that we can't just throw away parentheses and expect to get the same answer.  The parentheses are important.